# Does email use IP multicasting / IGMP?

Tags: email, networking, network-programming, ip, tcp

My professor told us in the class today that email/group mail uses IP multicast technology , when you type a group name having multiple email addresses and want to send an email to all of them. I was rather skeptical about it , I tried googling but I don't know much about multicast.

Is this even true ?

Comment: No. It uses SMTP which is defined over connection-orientied protocols like TCP, NCP, NITS, any other reliable end-to-end protocol. Not UDP, and not IP multicast.

Answer (score 2):

Your professor is not just wrong, he's completely ignorant on the workings of email.

When you send an email, it is passed to an MTA ([Message Transfer Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)) which looks up all the recipients, does an MX ([Mail Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)) lookup in DNS to find out the server for each domain, and sends a single copy of that email to the host for that domain, possibly with multiple recipients listed if it's going to more than one person at the same domain.

This is still a single TCP/IP connection, though one per destination domain.

If any recipient is a [list/alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_alias), the MTA will replace it with a new list of recipients, deliver what it can locally, and repeat the above for any off-site addresses.